# Avoid Round up Decimal - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to avoid round-up for two variables (inf_lat and inf_long) as I need to use them on leaflet map. This is how I display them on my project which returns a whole number instead of a decimal. It doesn't seem to be a problem but the marker on the leaflet map is spotted on the wrong location.

Display page

```
<!-- Inf Lat Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('inf_lat', 'Latitude:') !!}
    {{ $infrastructure->inf_lat }}
</div>

<!-- Inf Long Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('inf_long', 'Longtitude:') !!}
    {{ $infrastructure->inf_long }}
</div>
```

DB Migration

```
        $table->decimal('inf_lat', 9, 4);
        $table->decimal('inf_long', 9, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this

```
{{ number_format($infrastructure->inf_lat, 4, '', '.') }}
```

Comment: The solution is to change the data-type in the model. I tried that too but it doesn't work as the data passed from the model has ready been rounded-up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, Solution provided below

```
<!-- Inf Lat Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('inf_lat', 'Latitude:') !!}
    {{ number_format ($infrastructure->inf_lat, 4) }}
</div>

<!-- Inf Long Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('inf_long', 'Longtitude:') !!}
    {{ number_format($infrastructure->inf_long, 4) }}
</div>
```

Model

```
    'inf_lat' => 'double',  // I changed it from integer
    'inf_long' => 'double', // I changed it from integer
```